# What to do when categorical variables have low crosstabs?

Tags: categorical-data, small-sample

I am using an MLM model nesting counties in states. Some states have very small numbers of counties (n < 5). My intuition is telling me this is a problem, but I can't figure out how to phrase the question searching online and in my textbooks. Is this an issue and is there a general response to it?